# VPN openconnect pulse disconnects itself in Ubuntu 20

Tags: vpn, openconnect

Openconnect pulse VPN disconnects itself after sometime with "ESP detected dead peer" error in ubuntu 20. In ubuntu 18 it worked fine and kept on connected for long hours.
Please help to resolve this.

**IMPORTANT:**

- OpenConnect v8.0+ supports both the [Pulse protocol](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/pulse.html) and the [Juniper protocol](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/juniper.html). Most Pulse VPNs support *both*.
- The original description refers to "Pulse", but the poster was *almost certainly* connecting to the VPN using the "Juniper/oNCP" protocol, because OpenConnect developers subsequently discovered and fixed a bug in OpenConnect v8.04-v8.10 ([issue #322](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/openconnect/-/issues/322)) that precisely matches the symptoms described here, but specifically affects users of the Juniper protocol.

Comment: It might help if you clarify you release of Ubuntu. Most of us are using desktop and server releases of Ubuntu (which are *yy.mm* in format), and not specialist IoT or device releases that use *yy* format such as Ubuntu Core 20, or Ubuntu Core 18 (which can only use *snaps*).  I suspect you're using a *deb* based *yy.mm* format release, so why not say so instead of the *yy* format used by *snap* only releases.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior. I'm on Kubuntu 20.04.1. It seems to usually drop after 10-20 minutes, but it also appears to vary quite a bit.

Comment: Any solution to this? 
I am facing similar issue in Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: See my answer. We've recently diagnosed the bug, and I've written a fix for it which should be in the next OpenConnect release: https://askubuntu.com/a/1368954/139469

Answer (score 3):

> Openconnect pulse VPN disconnects itself after sometime with "ESP detected dead peer" error in ubuntu 20. In ubuntu 18 it worked fine and kept on connected for long hours. Please help to resolve this.

***UPDATE:*** This issue should be fixed in the recently-released [OpenConnect v8.20](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/openconnect-devel/2022-February/005089.html).

---

I presume you are actually using the `--protocol=nc` option, and thereby connecting with the older **Juniper/oNCP** protocol, rather than the newer (but less well-supported) **Pulse** protocol. (Most Juniper/Pulse servers support both.) Assuming so…

We've discovered a subtle bug in Juniper rekey/reconnection which was introduced in OpenConnect v8.04. Thanks to the efforts of a dedicated user who was able to contribute detailed logs (see [issue #322](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/openconnect/-/issues/322)), I've been able to write a fix for it: [merge request !293](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/openconnect/-/merge_requests/293).

Please compile from source and test, so we can confidently include this in the next release.

(I am one of the core OpenConnect developers.)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is UDP. you disable DTLS and ESP.
"openconnect --no-dtls"
if you use NetworkManager,

```
sudo mv /usr/sbin/openconnect /usr/sbin/openconnect.bin;
sudo vi /usr/sbin/openconnect
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/openconnect.bin --no-dtls "$@"
```

save /usr/sbin/openconnect

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/sbin/openconnect;
```

Comment: But with this parameter, the connection is barely breathing.
Work is not possible.

Comment: There is indeed a significant performance penalty with this flag. Does anyone have any clue why that is and how to avoid it?

Comment: See my answer. We've now discovered the bug that caused ESP rekeys not to work properly, and fixed it: https://askubuntu.com/a/1368954/139469

Answer (score 1):

For me the problematic version is 8.05-1, currently provided in Ubuntu 20.

Revert to the OpenConnect version of Ubuntu 18.04. If the packages in the following snippet are no longer available, check for new versions in https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/

```
sudo apt purge libopenconnect5 openconnect
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openconnect/libopenconnect5_7.08-3ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openconnect/openconnect_7.08-3ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i openconnect_7.08-3ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb libopenconnect5_7.08-3ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb 
sudo apt-mark hold libopenconnect5 openconnect
```

Comment: Now fixed. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1368954/139469

Answer (score 0):

**If you wish to revert to 18.04 packages**, besides `libopenconnect5` and `openconnect` you also need `network-manager-openconnect` and `network-manager-openconnect-gnome` re-installed back with the proper version, as they are removed once you purge openconnect. They also require `libnm-glib-vpn1` and `libnm-util2`.

You can check out the right download versions:

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/net/network-manager-openconnect
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/net/network-manager-openconnect-gnome
- https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libnm-util2
- https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libnm-glib-vpn1

So, a more complete list of commands is:

```
sudo apt purge libopenconnect5 openconnect

wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openconnect/libopenconnect5_7.08-3ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openconnect/openconnect_7.08-3ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb
    
wget http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/network-manager-openconnect/network-manager-openconnect_1.2.4-1_amd64.deb
wget http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/network-manager-openconnect/network-manager-openconnect-gnome_1.2.4-1_amd64.deb

wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/network-manager/libnm-glib-vpn1_1.6.2-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/network-manager/libnm-util2_1.6.2-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i openconnect_7.08-3ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb libopenconnect5_7.08-3ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb libnm-util2_1.6.2-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb libnm-glib-vpn1_1.6.2-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb network-manager-openconnect_1.2.4-1_amd64.deb network-manager-openconnect-gnome_1.2.4-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-mark hold openconnect libopenconnect5 network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

also a start (restart) of network manager might be needed:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Working flawlessly since I downgraded, used to get a `ESP detected dead peer` in less than 30 mins (most of the time in the first 10 mins), now i'm 4 hours in and VPN is still working!

### Monitoring

You can check out the logs with:

```
sudo journalctl -f -u NetworkManager.service
```

and watch out for smth like this "ESP detected dead peer"

Credit goes to prev [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1312935/1418518) by @tsiren